# Is this a vector space? If not, how can I make it one?

Tags: vector-spaces

$S= \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & 1\end{pmatrix}\vert a,b,c\in\Bbb R\right\}$

I know for a vector space we must:
$1.$ Define Addition
$2.$ Define Scalar Multiplication
$3.$ Have a set of numbers
$4.$ Have a Field

I know that we have already established $3$, and $4$. But for $1$ and $2$ is confusing.

Questions:
-How can I show that this has a zero vector?
-How can I show that all these numbers have an additive inverse?
-Do I have to change constant $1$ into a variable $d$ to make it a vector space?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use the normal addition and multiplication of a matrix by a number, it is not a vector space, because if you sum $2$ of the matrices the result will have $2$ in the bottom right corner and won't be an element of $S$. However you can make a vector space if you define the addition to be over the $3$ other slots of the matrices (similarly with the multiplication by a number). BTW this way the vector space will just be $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: what about scalar multiplication? is it okay for the 4th slot to equal k?

Comment: No @Mike the 4th slot should stay always 1. The multiplication should be only over the other 3 slots.